# sql - INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger - clean value before insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

i want to make a trigger to clean phone number from NonNumeric characters before inserting into table.

Phone table looks like this:

```
rowId     PhoneNumber  DepartmentId   ...
 1        12345678      4             ...
 2        23456789      5             ...
 3        34255467      6             ...
```

i create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insertPhone ON [Phone]
instead of INSERT as
begin
    declare @Phone nvarchar(50)
    declare @DepartmentId int
    ...
    select @Phone = (select PhoneNumber from inserted)
    select @DepartmentId = (select DepartmentId from inserted)
    ...
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Phone)>0
       set @Phone=STUFF(@Phone,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Phone),1,'')

    if (len(@Phone)>7) and (len(@Phone)<14) 
       INSERT INTO [Phone](PhoneNumber,DepartmentId,..) values (@Phone,@DepartmentId,..)
end
```

but while inserting i get the error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_insertPhone, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 1]
SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as as expression.
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You assume, in your trigger, than an `INSERT` only every effects one row. This is simply not true; it can affect 0+ rows. Also, a `TRIGGER` should have as minimal impact as possible, and a `WHILE` is going to be *far* from that. I suggest you completely rethink your approach here. What is the problem you are *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: SQL Server has statement triggers, not row triggers.  You must assume `inserted` has multiple rows.  You can factor your cleaning logic into a scalar UDF and do a set-based INSERT, or open a cursor over `inserted` and operate on each row.

Comment: my gole is very simple, making a trigger that will check and clean every phone number before inserted (clean it from NonNumeric characters, and insert only if it got 7-14 numbers).

Comment: What does an invalid phone number look like, and why are you not validating this in the front-end and alerting the user? Why are users allowed to enter anything other than digits? Or is your data coming from an external source? What do you want to happen with invalid data - presumably you'd want to log it and not just throw it away?

Comment: Wouldn't a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` to stop bad input be better, @rotem ...? Though assuming phone numbers are only made up of numbers is a mistake. How would you store international numbers, area codes (as some countries put them in parenthesis (`()`)) or a required extension number?

Comment: @stu , this is development server, only i use it. i want to make the trigger so i wont needed to check for proper values every time before i'm inserting records.

Comment: If this is just a development database why do you need to create a trigger? Just insert valid information. But as already mentioned a check constraint is the proper way to prevent crap data from entering your database.

Comment: @Larnu , some numbers may have characters like '+', '-', '( )' or more. but this is more like general question about how to make INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger for clean\check 
 correct values before inserting (i can think of other exp. like emails - insert only if like '%@%.%')

Comment: Again, with a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`. If you want to get clever, then add further validation in your presentation layer.

Comment: again, i may want to exctract area code or some but this is not only for phones. i want to know how to use INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger for any category.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use the `trigger` to edit or format any fields. Maybe, you have often seen these commands inside the `insert` command. For example: `insert into table1 (field1, field2) values (trim(@f1), @f2)`. That's why recommended to create a function for a do clean phone and use this in the `insert` command.

Example:

```
Create function clear_phone (@str varchar(200))  
returns varchar(200)  
begin  
    declare 
    @Phone varchar(200) 

    set @Phone = @str 

     WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Phone)>0
       set @Phone = STUFF(@Phone,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Phone),1,'')

    return @Phone  
end
```

Example for using this function in the `insert` command:

```
insert into table 
(
    departmentId, 
    phoneNumber
) 
values (
    @depId, 
    clear_phone(@phoneNum)
)
```

Comment: i actually did the same with separated function, and use it in the trigger. but i dont want to clean and check length inside every insert sentences .why cant i make trigger that will check and clean it for me?

Comment: @rotem IMO you are implementing a risky design. When a process inserts "x" into a table, it expects "x" to be added in the table if no error occurs. Here, the application will not find "x" after the insert because you "cleaned" it. Might seem like a trivial debate but you should only validate that the data is correct and not alter it as it passes through from application to table. Perhaps the application will print a confirmation after insertion. Now that confirmation is incorrect since "x" doesn't exist - you "cleaned" it into a different value.

Comment: but this is what i need, to clean/alter/check the data before it inserted. so insted of doing it every insert sentence i just want to bulid a trigger that will do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you use a `CHECK` constraint for this, and do verification and cleaning in the application code

For example

```sql
ALTER TABLE Phone
  ADD CONSTRAINT ValidPhone
    CHECK (PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%');
```

If you *really* want to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to enforce this, make sure it can deal with multiple (or zero) rows.

Also, an inline tally table is much quicker than a `WHILE` loop, so we can break out each character, check it, and aggregate back up.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_insertPhone ON [Phone]
instead of INSERT as

INSERT INTO [Phone]
  (PhoneNumber, DepartmentId,..)
SELECT v.Phone, i.DepartmentId,..)
FROM inserted i
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Phone = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(i.Phone, v.indx, 1), '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.indx
    FROM (VALUES   -- Recommended max phone length by ITU-T is 15
        (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15)
    ) v(indx)
    WHERE v.indx <= LEN(i.Phone)
      AND SUBSTRING(i.Phone, v.indx, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
) v
WHERE LEN(i.Phone) BETWEEN 7 AND 15;

GO
```